# LocalProtocolError( h11._util.LocalProtocolError: can't handle event type Response when role=SERVER and state=MUST_CLOSE

Tags: python, streaming, fastapi

I have the the following problem:
I have a Ubuntu 20.04.1 on which in Docker-container I have Python app using FastAPI to accept data stream from Appsflyer (POST-method).
Libraries versions are:

```
fastapi~=0.78.0
uvicorn~=0.17.6
pydantic~=1.9.1
aio_pika~=8.0.3
```

Every 10-12h I have the following error:
LocalProtocolError(
h11._util.LocalProtocolError: can't handle event type Response when role=SERVER and state=MUST_CLOSE
and due to it I have data loss. What can be the root cause of it? Thanks

Comment: Hi Semion, did you manage to solve your problem? Thanks

Comment: Hi Tommy, sadly but not.

Comment: how did you assess the data loss? Btw, check https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/111 and check if youve defined your paths with `def` instead of `async def`, and middlewares

Comment: also check https://github.com/freqtrade/freqtrade/issues/7905

Answer (score -1):

Try to checkout if there is an unhandled exception during response.
One of the possible variants is that the server rebooting or some other trouble with uvicorn.

This thread may help you
https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/96

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).